# Need help tuning sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

My mysql DB has become CPU hungry trying to execute a particularly slow query. When I do an explain, mysql says "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort". Please help deciphering and solving this puzzle.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `topsources` (
  `USER_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `UPDATED_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `URL_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SOURCE_SLUG` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `FEED_PAGE_URL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY_SLUG` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `REFERRER` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`,`URL_ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `FEED_PAGE_URL` (`FEED_PAGE_URL`),
  KEY `SOURCE_SLUG` (`SOURCE_SLUG`),
  KEY `CATEGORY_SLUG` (`CATEGORY_SLUG`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table has 370K rows...sometimes higher. The below query takes 10+ seconds.

```
SELECT topsources.SOURCE_SLUG, COUNT(topsources.SOURCE_SLUG) AS VIEW_COUNT
FROM topsources
WHERE CATEGORY_SLUG = '/newssource'
GROUP BY topsources.SOURCE_SLUG
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN topsources.USER_ID = 'xxxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY VIEW_COUNT DESC;
```

Here's the extended explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | topsources | ref  | CATEGORY_SLUG | CATEGORY_SLUG | 302     | const | 160790 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+----
```

-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+

Is there a way to improve this query? Also, are there any mysql settings that can help in reducing CPU load? I can allocate more memory that's available on my server.

Comment: HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN topsources.USER_ID = 'xxxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 this part is the most problematic I think let me think how to do this better

Comment: it'd help to post the exact output from the explain

Comment: Are updates happening while you are running the query?

Comment: Updates to the table keep happening all the time.

Comment: Something's not right: your `PRIMARY KEY` definition references columns that do not exist: `DATE_AND_HOUR` and `ITEM_ID`.

Comment: I had made some copy paste errors. Fixed it now. Problem statement is still the same.

Comment: I'm not an expert in tuning queries so won't venture an answer, but I'm sure it wouldn't take long just to try (if you haven't already) replacing `MAX(CASE WHEN topsources.USER_ID = 'xxxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0` with `COUNT(CASE WHEN topsources.USER_ID = 'xxxx' THEN 1 END) = 0` (or `COUNT(CASE topsources.USER_ID WHEN 'xxxx' THEN 1 END) = 0`).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing to help the query is an index on CATEGORY_SLUG, especially if it takes on many values.  (That is, if the query is highly selective.)  The query needs to read the entire table to get the results -- although 10 seconds seems like a long time.

I don't think the HAVING clause would be affecting the query processing.

Does the query take just as long if you run it two times in a row?

Comment: There's already an index on CATEGORY_SLUG. Please read the table structure above. Query almost always takes longer time to run.

Comment: Hmmm, how many category slugs are there?  Sometimes, indexes do more harm than good, especially when there are only a handful of values.

Comment: Less than 100 category slugs.

Comment: Try running the query ignoring the index, using the IGNORE INDEX hint (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).  It is possible that use of the index is causing pages to be read inefficiently (randomly and multiple times).

Comment: Ran the query with iGNORE INDEX hint. Didn't help.

Comment: well the having needs to scan every subset to get the max and a case is  multiplying that. and it can't use indexes for that task

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick if I read this my sql alteration correcty

```
SELECT topsources.SOURCE_SLUG, COUNT(topsources.SOURCE_SLUG) AS VIEW_COUNT
FROM topsources
WHERE CATEGORY_SLUG = '/newssource' and 
    topsources.SOURCE_SLUG not in (
        select distinct SOURCE_SLUG 
        from topsources 
        where USER_ID = 'xxxx'
        )
GROUP BY topsources.SOURCE_SLUG
ORDER BY VIEW_COUNT DESC;
```

Comment: This query returns a different result set. Not the same as original query.

Comment: Updated the query try that pls

Answer (score 0):

If there are many rows that match your CATEGORY_SLUG criteria, it may be difficult to make this fast, but is this any quicker?

```
SELECT ts.SOURCE_SLUG, COUNT(ts.SOURCE_SLUG) AS VIEW_COUNT 
FROM topsources ts
WHERE ts.CATEGORY_SLUG = '/newssource' 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM topsources ts2
                 WHERE ts2.CATEGORY_SLUG = '/newssource'
                   AND ts.SOURCE_SLUG = TS2.SOURCE_SLUG
                   AND ts2.USER_ID = 'xxxx')
GROUP BY ts.SOURCE_SLUG 
ORDER BY VIEW_COUNT DESC;
```

Comment: Query returns Unknown column 'TS2.SOURCE_SLUG' in 'where clause'

Comment: remove his line `AND ts.SOURCE_SLUG = TS2.SOURCE_SLUG`

Comment: If I remove that line, then this query returns empty result set

Answer (score 0):

Always hard to optimise something when you can't just throw queries at the data yourself, but this would be my first attempt if I was doing it myself:

```
SELECT t.SOURCE_SLUG, COUNT(t.SOURCE_SLUG) AS VIEW_COUNT
FROM topsources t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SOURCE_SLUG
    FROM topsources t
    WHERE CATEGORY_SLUG = '/newssource'
    AND USER_ID = 'xxx'
    GROUP BY .SOURCE_SLUG
) x USING (SOURCE_SLUG)
WHERE t.CATEGORY_SLUG = '/newssource'
AND x.SOURCE_SLUG IS NULL
GROUP BY t.SOURCE_SLUG
ORDER BY VIEW_COUNT DESC;
```